# What is the difference between DBCC cachedataremove and sp_unbindcache?

Tags: caching, sybase, database-performance

I would like to know the difference between DBCC cachedataremove and sp_unbindcache. because in my project i got permissions for unbindingcache but not to execute DBCC cachedataremove. I was assuming that they did pretty much the same thing.

SYBASE ASE 15.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_unbindcache is used to unbind and object from a **user-defined cache** whereas dbcc cachedataremove is use to remove an object from default data cache.

You cannot bind objects to default data cache explicitly only to user-defined caches.

Comment: thanks! your answer looks solid. Do you have a source where that is stated?

Comment: Only http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1572/html/sprocs/X93227.htm theres a section at the base about how objects are bound.

Comment: Thank you Rich! I've been on that page before but didn't get it by the time. Cheers